# MySQL sorting multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I want to sort on `strProjectName` and `strJobName`, **but** I want to prioritize `strProjectName`. Using the regular order by method: `ORDER BY strProjectName, strJobName ASC` does work, but not when sorting `DESC`, due to the fact it will sort on `strJobName` instead.

TL;DR: I want to sort first on `strProjectName` and **then** on `strJobName`. (And yes, there are more fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `ORDER BY strProjectName DESC, strJobName DESC` or else `ASC` will be assumed for `strProjectName`.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix ordering by different columns like so:

```
ORDER BY a DESC, b ASC
```